# How to merge field values into groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a similar HTML structure to this except I dynamically add a pair of fields (firstname & surname) as a user needs it.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <input id="firstname" type="text" value="firstname">
    <input id="surname" type="text" value="surname">
    <input id="firstname2" type="text" value="firstname">
    <input id="surname2" type="text" value="surname">
    </div>
```

I can get all the values into 1 long string and comma separated with

```
var vals = $('input').map(function()
{
   return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

However I want to merge the first 2 fields and join by a delimiter after the second field value e.g. `firstname surname, firstname2 surname2` and because I don't know which fields are created at POST, I can't specify them in my selector, so I need to look at grabbing them all from the wrapper.

Comment: You might want to consider why you would do this in the first place. If it's to send data via AJAX maybe you want to use `$(formSelector).serialize()`?

Comment: @PHPglue - frontend workaround for a crappy CMS, that you can't touch the core or upgrade in anyway :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var vals = $('input').map(function()
{
   return this.id.substring(0,6) == 'surname'?this.value+'~':this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Where, the last field's value alone will be appended with the Row Delimiter.

Note: I have based the logic off the ID attribute, but you might want to use which ever attribute is appropriate for your usage (like a css class!)

Comment: I'm still getting `firstname,surname,firstname2,surname2` as a result?

Comment: Doing this seems to work `var vals = $('input').map(function()
{
   return this.className.substring(0,7) == 'surname'?this.value+',':this.value;
}).get().join(' ');`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to assign the field that should be merged a class like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input class="firstclass" id="firstname" type="text" value="firstname">
<input class="firstclass" id="surname" type="text" value="surname">
<input class="secondclass" id="firstname2" type="text" value="firstname">
<input class="secondclass" id="surname2" type="text" value="surname">
</div>
```

and you should now be able to select the fields to merge using the class name instead of the element type `input`, like this

```
var vals = $('.firstclass').map(function()
{
   return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

**Alternatively**, restructure your html so that each pair is in it's own div, like this;

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="inputs">
      <input class="firstclass" id="firstname" type="text" value="firstname">
      <input class="firstclass" id="surname" type="text" value="surname">
   </div>
   <div class="inputs">
      <input class="firstclass" id="firstname" type="text" value="firstname">
      <input class="firstclass" id="surname" type="text" value="surname">
   </div>
</div>
```

and then, first select all the `inputs` as an array like this;

```
var inputs = $(".inputs');
```

and the loop over the inputs and join the fields as what you did in the first example.

```
for (var i in inputs) { 
    var vals = $(i).find('input').map(function()
    {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(',');
    ... do something with vals...
}
```

Comment: Sorry not quite understanding, if I add a class to each pair, my selector is still going to know which pairs are available to use that selector? but since the user can add multiple pairs of fields, I don't know which selectors are needed to select them... if that makes sense?

Comment: You will have to keep track of what pairs you have added.

Comment: Alternatively (and better) you would restructure your html, so the pairs are grouped in divs, and you can just extract the divs in the wrapper